# error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-fullstack

Getting this error - :

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
at module.exports (F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at F:\Projects mrcaption49\Review Done - DJANGO_REACT_APNA_VERSION\DjangoReact APNAVERSION\DjangoReact23002021\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.